# marker image in google maps to blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to blink or animate the marker in google maps.I tried using CALayer but it just blink once. The "pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX" code is not working .It is blinking only once.Is there any way to solve my problem??

```
   func loadMap(){
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 15)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

    // change map type
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal

    self.view = mapView

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)

    //custom marker
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "maprymarker")
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    pulseAnimation.duration = 1
    pulseAnimation.fromValue = 0
    pulseAnimation.toValue = 1
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
    marker.layer.addAnimation(pulseAnimation, forKey: nil)

}
```

Comment: Know one know the answer

Answer (score 1):

Add the animation delegate methods,then call the same function again.

```
func blink(){
    var i:Int = 0
    for marker in markerBlink{
        let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        pulseAnimation.delegate = self
        pulseAnimation.duration = 1.0
        pulseAnimation.fromValue = 1
        pulseAnimation.toValue = 0
        pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
        marker.layer.addAnimation(pulseAnimation, forKey: "\(++i)")
    }

}

override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if flag{

        blink()

    }
}
```